# Gulp error, cannot find module 'vinyl'

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I have been struggling with getting flux/react to work properly and thought that my npm, node or gulp versions were to old.

So I updated everything to the latest version and now I get the following error when i run gulp in ALL my projects:

```
module.js:340
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'vinyl'
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
      at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
      at require (module.js:385:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-util/index.js:2:9)
      at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
      at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
      at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

I have:

1. Uninstalled node and gulp through npm.
2. Uninstalled npm.
3. Installed node and npm via https://nodejs.org/en/
4. Installed gulp through npm

And it's still not working..

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `npm install --save vinyl` ? Also, to make switching between version of node and npm easier consider using `nvm`.

Comment: I was getting the same error the other day. Updating the global gulp installation worked for me.

Comment: @jm_____ i can't run that command.
I am kind of new to both terminal and npm.
I forgot to say that I also reinstalled vinyl

Comment: @KeithRousseau is there a "local" installation?
I reinstalled gulp with npm.

Comment: If you don't include the -g flag, it will install in a local node_modules directory. --save or --save-dev will add it to your package.json

Comment: Ok, so if I have installed packages without -g I could have packages all over the place?
Ok, so I then need to stand in the root directory of my project and run the --save command?

Comment: @KeithRousseau You are the boss!!
Reinstalled gulp with -g and now it works :)
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

As @keithRousseau pointed out, when I reinstalled the packages I forgot to install them with the parameter -g to install them as global packages.

Reinstalled them with -g and now it works!